# Display int as QString in QTableView column

Tags: c++, qt, model, qtgui, qtcore

I have a `QTableView` linked to a `QSqlTableModel`. In this table, there is a column that is a integer. Each value of this one matches with a `QString`. I already used a `QComboBox` delegate in order to select the `QString` when editing. But when the value is edited, it is displayed as an integer.

What I want to do is to display the value as a `QString` with the corresponding integer value.

I looked in `QAbstractProxyModel` class but I am not totally sure that it can solve my problem.

Can you confirm this way (subclassing `QAbstractProxyModel`) or using another one?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reimplement your delegate `paint` method to display text.

You can check classic [star delegate example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/itemviews-stardelegate.html). In your case everything is much simplier: you should draw just a text.

Comment: Thank your answer. I am looking at your solution. I will tell you if it works.